# Incorrect system time when I set it to automatically update from Internet

Tags: system, time

My time zone is IST. Incorrect system time gets populated, when I try to update it automatically from the Internet.
I have updated appropriate time zone.

Comment: by how much time is the clock off? Are dual booting with windows?

Comment: can you provide the output of `timedatectl status`

Comment: This had some thing to do with my dual boot with Windows 7 I believe. I un-installed Windows 7 from my Desktop.. don't have this problem now.